# Permission issue for appium chrome borwser

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium, appium-android, saucelabs

I am implementing an appium test on remote android driver, with chrome browser for loading urls. 
Some of the Urls are pdfs, and chrome asks to store those files. and appears that chrome doesnt have access to filesystem to store those files, which results in a dialog like below.

Please help me pass that dialog without any manual inputs.

[image: File permission dialog]

Upon clicking `continue`, it will load actual permissions dialog from Android.

Here is my code initialize appium capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android();
    caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.9.1");
    caps.setCapability("deviceName","Samsung Galaxy S9 Plus HD GoogleAPI Emulator");
    caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
    caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
    caps.setCapability("platformName","Android");
    caps.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
    caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
    caps.setCapability("chromedriverArgs", "--allow-file-access-from-files");
    caps.setCapability("maxDuration", 10000);
```

and this is the snippet I use to load a Url

```
        driver.navigate().to("http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf");
```

`autoGrantPermission` also doesnt work in this case because chrome is already installed. Appium team has already rejected this issue - 
https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10008

Please help!

Comment: Go to device setting>App>Chrome>Permission and allow storage permission. This should work.

Comment: There is no physical device. I create a device on the fly using saucelabs service

Comment: Assuming you're paying SauceLabs for this service, they should be able to provide you the answer. I'm sure it's not the first time a customer has needed to do this.

A quick search of their docs leads me to believe you need to be using a real device. I've not used S-Labs, but I'm assuming you can choose between real or simulated cloud devices when setting up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed I had very hard time finding out the solution, but eventually I found a workaround.

- The best workaround would have been reinstalling the chrome package. I tried that, but I could not start chrome after reinstalling it, as I had no access to shell, and chromedriver complained. So I left that track.
- I tried getting hold of `adb` command or `mobile:changePermissions` but for that you need to use server flag `--relaxed-security` while starting the server, and saucelabs doesnt provide any handy interface to start the server with this flag.

The last resort, I found a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51241899/4675277 . But just that was not sufficient, because it helped me fix chrome alert, but later on it popped up with another alert with `allow` and `deny`, for which another solution in the same question helped me. So this is the code I eventually used -

```
driver.navigate().to("http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf");
    String webContext = ((AndroidDriver)driver).getContext();
    Set<String> contexts = ((AndroidDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
    for (String context: contexts){
        if (context.contains("NATIVE_APP")){
            ((AndroidDriver)driver).context(context);
            break;
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/button1")).click();
    contexts = ((AndroidDriver)driver).getContextHandles();
    for (String context: contexts){
        if (context.contains("NATIVE_APP")){
            ((AndroidDriver)driver).context(context);
            break;
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button")).click();
    ((AndroidDriver)driver).context(webContext);
```

This helps allow all permissions required.