# How to handle the Mobile web windows notification

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

while running the script in mobile browser using appium , how to handle the windows notification or how to click on accept of block button

Tried using robot class.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZbK7.png)

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Hi Andi ,I have added screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174794/appium-in-web-app-unable-to-tap-allow-permission-button-in-notification-pop-up

Comment: @AnujBansal    adding screenshot to the question is bad practice no one will write it for you by looking at image also any of answers are helpful to you upvote/accept them as appreciation of help and other members can relate to the working answer